# What is the `Assert.That` property for?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, .net-core

Does anybody know what this `Assert.That` property is for? All members of `Assert` are static so what is the point of getting an instance?

I know that NUnit has a method `Assert.That` for hamcrest matchers but a property does not seem to make sense. Maybe this property is for custom assertions as extension methods on `Assert`?

[image]

Comment: If you expand the 3 dots `...` you will see in the remarks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**Assert.That Property**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.that?view=mstest-net-1.1.17)

Gets the singleton instance of the Assert functionality.

> Users can use this to plug-in custom assertions through C# extension methods.
>   For instance, the signature of a custom assertion provider could be "public static void IsOfType(this Assert assert, object obj)"
>   Users could then use a syntax similar to the default assertions which in this case is "`Assert.That.IsOfType<Dog>(animal);`"
>
> More documentation is at https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs.